# Couchbase - java 2.1.1 SDK, When I read document with time to live, the expiry is always zero

Tags: java, couchbase

The code below demonstrates the issue. I insert a document with a ttl of 2 seconds. If I read it immediately, a value will be returned. If I read it after few seconds it will be empty - the document has already expired.

***HOWEVER*** - in both cases the "expire" field of the document metadata returns zero.
Any idea why is that?

```
int expiry = 2;
JsonObject val = JsonObject.empty().put("somekey", "just some value");            


JsonDocument newDoc = JsonDocument.create("ttl.test", expiry,val);
JsonDocument retVal = bucket.insert(newDoc);

JsonDocument readDoc = bucket.get("ttl.test");

if(readDoc == null){
       System.out.println("1. null");
} else {
       System.out.println("1. not null: " + readDoc.expiry());
}

// Wait for slightly more than the TTL
try {
       Thread.sleep(2500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}

readDoc = bucket.get("ttl.test");
if(readDoc == null){
       System.out.println("2. null");
} else {
       System.out.println("2. not null: " + readDoc.expiry());
}
```

**The output is:**

1. not null: 0
2. null

Therefore – TTL works ok, however the expiry is always zero in the JsonDocument I read from server;

Answer (score 3):

This probably could be better documented, but it is by design in the Memcached protocol (see it [here](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/MemcacheBinaryProtocol)), the expiry isn't transmitted in the extra bytes of a get, only on mutating operations.

Comment: Thanks Simon, so what would be the way to read the expiration date of the document? management console doesn't show this information as well.

Comment: I have the same question. In the old 1.x client i can get expiry using client.getKeyStats(viewRow.getId()).get().get("key_exptime");